# Connection Timeout Problem in Inter service communication in microservices when deployed on kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I am working on a demo project , which has 5 microservices - discovery server , api-gateway , user-order-detail , order and user service.

I will expose the order and user service internally on GKE

I will expose the user-order-detail service externally which will call the other two services using a rest endpoint

Services that are up on google kubernetes engine:

user-order-detail LoadBalancer
kubernetes ClusterIP
order-management LoadBalancer
user-management LoadBalancer

**user-order-detail hits an endpoint to retrieve all users. I am getting this error :No matches for the virtual host name :user-management**

Code :

```
String url = "user-management/user";
InstanceInfo instance = eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka("user-management", false);
Object response = restTemplate.getForObject(instance.getHomePageUrl() + url +"/" + userId, Object.class);
```

I am having problem in inter-service communication.please help

**UPDATE:**
I was able to redirect my service,but I am getting connection timeout error.How should I solve this?

I/O error on GET request for "http://user-management/user-management/user/1": Operation timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the port for your service and target port 
port can be 80
targetport

Comment: yes, it was listening on port 80 and then redirecting it to you 9106